# Dropdown menu not being displayed on clicking

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a website and the [HomePage](https://cure4incurables.in) is working perfectly, but the dropdown menu which should get displayed on mobiles/small screens on clicking the down pointing triangle, next to the "Links", is not displaying/showing the top navbar links on any other webpage, for example [Corns](https://cure4incurables.in/corns.html). I have tried a lot of things and given up! Somebody please help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had missed a bracket in the Javascript!

Comment: Every bracket, semi-colon and "<" or ">" tag is important!